# Coulomb's Force $\pm$ $\mathbf{sign}$ depend on both "$q_1q_2$ and $\hat{r}$" or "only $\hat{r}$"?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

Pls using diagram explain how coulomb's law in vector form work. Show every possible combination with **direction vector** , **sign** and **convention**.

1. $ \mathbf{q_1q_2} :  $ $\pm$ sign
2. $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ : $\pm$ sign , director vector and convention e.g: $\hat{r}_{12}$
3. $\mathbf{\vec{F}}$ : $\pm$sign, direction vector and  which depend on *$q_1q_2$* and *$\hat{r}$* and convention e.g: $\vec{F}_{21}$.
4. Choice of coordinate axis can also change the sign.

$$ $$

Comment: The wordings of your question seems like a homework problem, is it?

Comment: If you think it can be change in better form pls edit. Thanks

Comment: Do you understand physics which underlie in Coulomb interaction? It seems not. It seems that you "ask for asking", without any efforts for checking books, papers etc. This question is perfectly covered in any school textbook for physics.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov Pls share your knowledge with every possible combination of charges , direction vector "$\hat{r}$,$\vec{F}$" , sign and conventions, it looks very complicated that's why i asked question.

Answer (score 4):

The actual form of Coulomb Law states mathematically : $$ \mathbf{F} = k \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2} \hat r$$ 
Now, if we assume that the vector from $q_1$ to $q_2$  is $\vec{r_{1~to~2}}$ then the force on $q_2$ due to $q_1$ is $$  \mathbf{F_{on 2 by 1}}= k \frac{q_1 q_2}{r_{1~to2}^2} \hat r_{1~to~2}$$ 
If the charges are of same sign then you can see that force will along the vector pointing from $q_1$ to $q_2$ that is it will be repulsive. If they would have opposite signs then we will get a negative sign in front of the whole expression and hence the force will point opposite to $r$ (that it force will point from $q_2$ to $q_1$) and it will be attractive.

So, you see $\hat r_{1~to~2}$ always points from $q_1$ to $q_2$ (when we are calculating the force on $q_2$) and the direction of the force is taken care by the sign of the charges.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pls mention convention *r* like $\hat{r}_{12}$ and if possible it is request you that share diagram in which direction vector and *r* and *F* with charges sign. because if i make diagram mistake can be happen.

Comment: This is a good answer, but some ambiguity can be removed by writing $\bf{F}_{12} = k \frac{q_1q_2}{|\bf{r}_{12}|^2}\hat{\bf{r}}_{12}$ where $X_{12} = X_1-X_2$.

Comment: Thanks @garyp, pls mention the $\pm$ sign of F depend on both $q_1q_2$ and $\hat{r}$ or only on $\hat{r}$

Comment: There are no signs in front of ${\bf F}$ or anywhere else.   Rather, it's always an implied positive sign.  All other signs are taken care of by the definition of $X_{12}$ and the signs of the charges.

Comment: I know there is no sign in front of $\mathbf{F}$ , i am asking there are two things which in results responsible for sign of  'F' . One is multiplication of $q_1q_2$ and anthor is $\hat{r}$. Do you mean whether one charge plus another minus, $r_{12}$ or $r_{21}$ , F is always positive?

Comment: I should make clear the ${\bf F}_{ab}$ is the force on $a$ due to $b$, and ${\bf r}_{ab}$ is the position of $a$ relative to $b$.

Comment: Well $\hat{{\bf r}}$ is a vector, so it has no intrinsic sign.   The product of the charges takes care of "like charges repel, and unlike charges attract".  Perhaps that's your issue.  Defined as I have done, the force is always parallel to the unit vector.  Whether they point in the same direction (repel) or opposite direction (attract) is determined by the product of the charges.

Comment: I don't know why stackexchange community is not behaving good whenever question is asked. They are not trying to answer the question just misbehave. If we have a knowledge of everything why would we ask questions. I am not talking about you @garyp, but most people .

Comment: @garyp I have made the edits the way you said. I have learned giving answers like this from great men like you.

Comment: @123 Come [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100303/general-chat) and we will discuss your doubts even further.

Comment: @Knight i am not able to write in the chatroom. There is no comment box.

Comment: @123 Use the laptop or different browser.

Comment: @Knight thanks now i found comment box. Pls come here . There are so many confusions about these topic. Pls everyone who can clear this topic come as well. If community respect the questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this type of problem:

A "+" is used to indicate positive charge.  Example: + 10 micro-Coulombs

A "-" is used to indicate negative charge.

r is by default always positive, and is the distance between the charges, or the distance between the centers of charged objects

Units should probably be standard SI units

Now, when applying the equation $F=\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$, the force between the two charges always acts in the direction of the line connecting the charges.  If the force is negative, the objects are attracted to each other.  If the force is positive, the objects repel each other.

Comment: Hello David, Is there any influence on sign of coordinates axis line e.g: x-axis. If it is what if we flip positive and negative axis. Also how can position vector $r$ have always positive sign. because $\pm$ sign defined the direction of vector.

Comment: You get to decide on your coordinate system when you set up the problem.  However you set up your coordinate system, the same concepts that I listed still apply, and it's your job to decide on the exact values of coordinates and direction that apply to that system.  Also note: a "+" result or a "-" result in the calculation of force has nothing to do with your choice of coordinate system.  That information is used to determine attraction or repulsion.

Comment: I think it is waste of time to post any question on stackexchange. Whenever i have posted a question beside few peoples every one do a negative vote. If the question is always level of school standard so answers should more easy to explain. why this is problematic to answer and satisfy so other peoples can also read the answer. What i guess after so many post, except few people community members have $\textbf{NO KNOWLEDGE}$ of science. If they have they should answer. It should not be a problem to answer a question.Sorry to say that this is truth..! and they are just doing time pass here.

Comment: I am really disappointed to the rude behavior of the community, even they never take questions seriously. They never answer seriously, i don't know what they are doing here and what is the main purpose of this website. Every single time i found this same behavior and non seriousness.(Exclude few good peoples).

Comment: @123, hopefully, you didn't read my previous reply as rude.  There is no unique coordinate system or unique coordinate designation for one of your two point charges ... you have to decide on that when you set the problem up.  Once you locate one charge, the other charge's location is dependent on the location of the first charge.  That fact is a math thing that requires a decision on your part, not a refusal to answer the question.

Comment: Dear @David White , i am not talking about you. you and other few peoples like knight replied and i am very thankful . But from most other peoples i found this behavior. Even this is my all the way experience from previous posts as well.

Comment: Because previously i thought stackexchange has community of super duper knowledge and experienced in there field. But i am totally disappointed with most answers and even i can think way better than that. Most community peoples just ignore question vote negatively , bad comments, saying these are very elementary questions. If these are elementary questions why thy don't answer? WHY?